# identifying the architecture of an application

Tags: c++, wpf, windows, forms, winapi

Is there a way to figure out which architecture an application is implementing?

I'm trying to figure out whether either Win32, WPF or Windows Form is being used by a 3rd party application.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Is there any specific reason you need that information? That is a difficult question to answer.

Comment: I don't think it is  an exclusive choice. An application could use a combination  of those.

Comment: An application using WPF and/or Windows Forms will **always** call into the Win32 API. Likewise, a pure native Win32 application can host the CLR using the [native hosting facilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9x0wh2z3.aspx). Assuming that those 3 platforms are mutually exclusive leads to asking for something, that doesn't exist. Unless you explain, why you think that you need to know, you cannot hope to get much helpful feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at the EXEs and DLLs of the application, e.g. using ILSpy.

WPF and WinForms is as far as I know limited to the .NET framework. So if it is not a .Net EXE, and ILSpy does not parse it, it is probably Win32.

If it is a .Net EXE, look at the references. If only WPF specific dlls are referenced, it is probably WPF. If only WinForms specific dlls, probably WinForms. If both, you need to trace the program starting from the main method to find evidence, which API is used.

But either way, it is no strong evidence. Both APIs could be mixed, and there could be Windows or Elements of each used. Since WinForms is a wrapper of the native Win32 API, whenever you use WinForms you actually also use the Win32 API.

So it probably depends on what you specifically need to know.